# Anchor tag onclick event in aspx page works in IE (11) but fails to respond in Chrome and Firefox

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net

Anchor tag onclick event in aspx page works in IE but fails to respond in Chrome and Firefox

Code:

```
<ul> <li>   <a  Href='Sample.aspx?ID=123' onclick = 'parent.window.frames['FrameRightPanel'].location=this.href;return false;' > Sample </li></ul>
```

works perfectly fine in IE(version 11) but fails to do any action in Chrome and Firefox. What am I missing? Any help.

Comment: You can't have unescaped single quotes (`'`) within an attribute value delimited by single quotes. Change the outer quotes to double quotes (`"`).

Comment: I tried this change but didn't have any effect.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why I didn't realize this a while ago, but why don't you just remove the quotes from the `FrameRightPanel`...

```
onclick = 'parent.window.frames[FrameRightPanel].location=this.href;return false;' >
```

The browser should interpret that as JS code and the value of FrameRightPanel would be substituted.

Comment: I did try that :). When I remove the quotes, the pages open in a new browser window instead of iframe -FrameRightPanel. This happens in IE too.

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution. The IFrame was missing the name attribute!!

Earlier code was

```
<iframe id="FrameRightPanel"  ></iframe>
```

added Name

```
<iframe id="FrameRightPanel" name="FrameRightPanel"   ></iframe>
```

Now it works in IE, Chrome & FireFox.